# how to get version of typescript in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, version

hy, can anyone explain me why these three: Help-> About MSVS,package.json and"developer command prompt for 2015"-> `tsc -v` shows different typescript versions? I build my web using VS so which one is the right? So, the question is how to get the version of ts I am using now? And how to make VS to be up to date with ts and how to check if it is updated?